# AppConfig override restricts first makemigration

Tags: django

I am overriding the AppConfig and adding below in `__init__`

```
default_app_config = 'api.apps.AppnameConfig'
```

which has some models check I want to create them if doesnot exits all works fine. But when I am deploying this to another machine

> python manage.py makemigrations

fails obviously because there are no tables created as there is no migration on fresh project. It is raising `ProgrammingError` I can do try pass on this but I dont want to go this way.

I also checked if migrations folder exists works fine but again fails on migrate.

Please suggest best way to do this.

Comment: How does the command fail? `makemigrations` should never fail, be there migrations or not.

Comment: `makemigrations` does *not* create tables, `migrate` will run the migrations.

Comment: @AKX yes you can fail it easily try running runserver without creating database here database is present but no relations as no migration is applied yet.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari: as said, you need to run `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  yes you are right but it fails on migrate too. I need to run makemigrations first isnt it? even if I dont it fails when I comment the default_app_config it runs but then I can not perform model check I am doing

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in the `AppConfig`. A [datamigration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) is another possibility. If you really want to do this in the `AppConfig`, then catching the exception sounds ok to me.

Comment: @Alasdair that will work I was thinking of if I can count number of migrations or a check whether fresh deployment instead of try catch. Will do if can not it is simple solution indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by checking the tables introspection returns `[]` if no migration is ever applied in `__init__`

```
from django.db import connection

if connection.introspection.table_names():
    default_app_config = 'pathto.AppnameConfig'
```