# Django Makemigrations not working with ForeignKey field to an app that has AppConfig

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-migrations, django-apps

We have an app called `sessions`, and since Django has similar `django.contrib.sessions` app, we need to create an AppConfig to fix the "duplicate app" error, that is, we set the app label as `common.sessions`.

So, we have this folder/files structure:

```
common
    sessions
        __init__.py
        apps.py
        models.py
```

`__init__.py`

```py
default_app_config = 'common.sessions.apps.CommonSessionsConfig'
```

`apps.py`

```py
class CommonSessionsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'common.sessions'
    label = 'common.sessions'
```

`models.py`

```py
class SessionEventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class SessionEventTypeMapping(models.Model):
    session_event_type = models.ForeignKey(SessionEventType)
```

`settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'common.sessions',
    ...
)
```

Running `manage.py migrations` will throw this error:

```py
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 111, in _detect_changes
    self.new_apps = self.to_state.apps
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 59, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 166, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/virtualenv/backoffice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 248, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model))
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field common.sessions.SessionEventTypeMapping.session_event_type: common.sessions.common.sessions.SessionEventType
```

Apparently, it fails on this part and could not locate the `SessionEventType` class/model even though they're just in the same `models.py` file, and ended up looking for `common.sessions.common.sessions.SessionEventType` which is strange:

```py
session_event_type = models.ForeignKey(SessionEventType)
```

Tried also this variant:

```py
session_event_type = models.ForeignKey('common.sessions.SessionEventType')
```

but it didn't help, as well as this related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870232/appconfig-override-restricts-first-makemigration). By the way, we're still using **Py2**/**Django1.8** since it's a huge project and we couldn't upgrade the version easily. Are we missing something? Checked the AppConfig/ForeignKey docs but seems no related info for it. No thrown error also if we don't use an FK field (i.e. non-relation field migrations are ok). We just want the `makemigrations` to work.